# Monotouch IPA replaces another application signed on the same computer

Tags: c#, ipad, xamarin.ios, ipa

I have an application written on C#

The problems is following: there is some application on iPad, and this application written and signed on the computer I building and signing my application on.

So, there is a problem - when I'm trying to install my application, the previous installed application is replaced. What can I do to make these application be setted up simultaneously?

Comment: Why are your statements so vague?  A signed application shouldn't conflict with another application unless it was signed by the same cert and was named exactly the samething.  More specific information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in provisioning profile - I had to create one for my application

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a different bundle id for the second app?

You should generally use the convention:

`com.yourcompanyname.yourappname`

So `yourappname` would be different for each app, and not install on top of the other one.